# Referencing value and calling methods in generic class types

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin coming from C#. Currently I am trying to setup a class that takes in a couple of interchangeable generic types, the internal code of this class is a spring service end-point.

I have started with something like below, however I seem to have trouble with the syntax to reference the parameters of the request body as well as calling a method, which are of the types passed in through the class constructor. Syntax of generics and reflection does not seem that straight forward and most of the Kotlin examples I have been digging up has not seem to covered precisely what I am trying to do (if even possible). The object instance of type1 will be passed in through the body parameter and the object instance of type2 should be passed in through the constructor (syntax is probably not right).

Planning to use this as a template to setup several end-points based on the same base code but with different requests and services classes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod
import javax.validation.Valid

open class Base <T1,T2>(t1: Class<T1>, t2: Class<T2>) {

  @Autowired
  var type1 = t1

  @Autowired
  var type2 = t2

  @ApiOperation(value = "API 1", response = myResponse::class)
  @ApiResponses(value = *arrayOf(
    ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful", response = CcdaResponse::class),
    ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid", response = Void::class)))
  @RequestMapping(
    value = "/myEndPoint",
    produces = arrayOf("application/json"),
    consumes = arrayOf("application/json"),
    method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST)
  )

  fun endpoint(
    @ApiParam(value = "Options", required = true)
    @Valid
    @RequestBody
    body: Class<T1>
  ): ResponseEntity<myResponse> {
    val r = myResponse()
    val response: ResponseEntity<myResponse>
    response = ResponseEntity(r, HttpStatus.OK)
    try {

      //payload
      val parameters = Parameters().apply {
        Id1 = type1::body.Id1.get()
        Id2 = type1::body.Id2.get()
        Id3 = type1::body.Id3.get()
        Id4 = type1::body.Id4.get()
        v = type1::body.v.get()
      }
      //Do stuff like calling method in class of type2 passed in
      val d = type2.getViewModel(parameters)

      r.status = "ok"

    } catch (e: Exception) {
      r.message = e.toString()
      r.status = "error"
    } finally {
    }
    return response
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the _class_ itself in the constructor (roughly corresponds to `Type` in .NET) or an instance? Since you state "object instance of type2 should be passed in through the constructor", it looks like you want `T1`/`T2` instead of `Class<T1>`/`Class<T2>`

Comment: I plan to pass in an instance of type1 through the body parameter in the endpoint function, and an instance of type2 through the constructor of the Base class. I assume I need the types themselves passed in, might need a 3rd parameter with the actual object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types of the parameters are passed in through the type arguments when creating an instance (the same as Java). So you do need to pass in the types themselves, adding a `Class` parameter just isn't the correct syntax.

I believe this is what you are looking for (omitted some code for brevity).

```
open class Base<T1, T2> (@Autowired var t2: T2) {

    @Autowired var type1: T1? = null

    fun endpoint(
        @ApiParam(value = "Options", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody
        body: T1
    ): ResponseEntity<MyResponse> {
        type1 = body
    }

}
```

Then, for instance, you can create an instance of this class with the types `Int` and `String` (for `T1` and `T2` respectively) in the following manner.

```
val t2 = "t2"
val base = Base<Int, String>(t2)
```

Or you can subclass the `Base` class with any (or none) of the types specified.

```
class SubBase(t2: String): Base<Int, String>(t2)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One question popped up. How do I access attributes in the type1/body object? .Same for the t2 parameter passed into the constructor.

Comment: @aggaton You can only access the properties of the generic type (which defaults to the type `Any?`). I suggest you take a look at the [`is` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) or [type projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) in order to access the properties of a more specific type. Or you can override any function in a subclass or an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) to have access to the types specified by the type arguments.